# Firebase Functions + Express + subfolder names in routes + logs including route names?

Tags: rest, firebase, express

I want to use Firebase Functions and Express to have routes like the following:

```
/users/:uid
/users/:uid/create
/users/:uid/update
/users/:uid/addFriend/:toAddUid
/users/:uid/sendMessage/:sendToUid
```

You can do this using Express e.g.

https://medium.com/@atbe/firebase-functions-true-routing-2cb17a5cd288

with a line like this:

```
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(expressApp);
```

However, the logging you get is now very bad. On deploy, you're only told the route "api" was deployed. The runtime logs when functions are running are grouped into a single function called "api" so the dashboard won't tell you how much time was spent in each function, number of calls etc.

How can I get the route names I'd like with decent logging?

Comment: File a feature request describing what you'd like to see.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: @DougStevenson Are you confirming then this currently isn't possible? Is this possible without using Express?

Comment: Not that I know of.  In any event, it's never wrong to submit a feature request.  Worst case is that nothing happens.